# Open socket between windows browser to Linux server

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, vps, serversocket

I want to get live pricing data e.g: EUR/USD live price from other website.

I have

- Windows VPS - Running website - from where i want to get live pricing data
- Linux VPS - my target where i want to send data.

I want to quick price update from other website to my Linux server. How to open socket between windows chrome browser and Linux server?

Which programming language help me to achieve my task?

Comment: You can literally use any language that is convenient. What languages do you program in?

Comment: I can program in any language, it will take me to understand maximum of 1 hour to understand any new language. i search in google there a 3 languages that help to open socket, Node.js, socket.io and python. i can work on these languages... i just want to know which is best for my case?

Comment: But if i can do with PHP that is awesome... as i found on google, it is hard to implement and not a good socket language.

Comment: If you don't have a preference, just use any language you're comfortable with. For just simple socket stuff, I often use node. But like I said, you can use any language that is convenient. (although, it does have the requirement that it needs to be able to run as an application/service)